# Inside and Out radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I think there is a way to do an inside radius, and an outside radius, but how? I want to have a spawnpoint, where @a[r=30] is in gamemode a, and everyone outside is gamemode s. How would I write this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `rm` (Radius minimum) argument. For example:

```
/gamemode @a[rm=30] s
```

In 1.13 the commands are:

```
gamemode @a[distance=..30] adventure
gamemode @a[distance=30..] survival
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple, but I guess it was so simple I couldn't find a YT video on it... :)

Comment: Remark: Tagging the players who go in and out and only setting their gamemode once improves performance and causes prevents output spam if commandBlockFeedback is on.